# I got two patterns but I need one regex solution

Tags: regex

I got two kinds of patterns from which I should extract the 'A', 'B' and 'C'

```
INTERFACE(A, B, C, D) and INTERFACE(E, F, G).
```

The regex pattern which I tried was like this `INTERFACE\((.+),(.+),(.+)` but no success when I get the capture, and the result which I receive is A, B mixed in capture group 1 when I give 4 input pattern.

From the above two interface patterns I'm looking for A, B, C and also E, F, and discard the others.

Comment: I'd recommend a two-step solution for readability and simplicity. First, capture the lists in a non-greedy fashion: `\((.+?)\)`. This will give you `A, B, C, D` and `A, B, C` (allowing you to keep them distinct). From there, you may split the string by the delimiter `,\s+`.

Comment: What would you want to extract if the input was `INTERFACE(A, B, C, D) and INTERFACE(E, F, G).`?

Comment: Can you please add which language you're using?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I want A, B, C, D seperately in their own capture groups and E, F, G in the own groups.

Comment: @VB  Re: _"I want A, B, C, D seperately in their own capture groups and E, F, G in the own groups"_ - Ok, please update the question to make that clear. It's a bit ambigous as it is written now. Adding more examples and the expected captures (and non-captures) would also improve your chances to get a really great answer.

Comment: @VB now you do not want D & G to be matched? :/

Comment: @KiranParajuli: No. D and G need not to be matched.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Updated my question. Can you please upvote my question again. Because I'm unable to ask any further questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 3 capture groups, you can use a negated character `[^` class inside the first 3 groups, and a negated character class at the end one to match till the closing parenthesis:

```
INTERFACE\(([^(),]*),([^(),]*),([^,()]*)[^()]*\)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cePnDp/1)

Or without matching leading whitespace chars ans at least a single non whitespace char except `,` `(` `)`

```
INTERFACE\(([^(),\s]*),\s*([^(),\s]+),\s*([^,()\s]+)[^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fkc7NE/1)

For 2 or 3 capture groups:

```
INTERFACE\(([^,\s()]+),\s*([^,\s()]+)(?:,\s*([^,\s()]))?,\s*[^,\s()]+\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b254GB/1)

Comment: this matches the last item `G` from the second pattern. as per the question only `E` and `F` need to be catched.

Comment: @KiranParajuli Yeah the question was changed. I have added an update.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this and perform string splitting afterwards:

```py
r"INTERFACE\(((?:[A-Z],\s?){2,})[A-Z]\)"gm
```

- I find no general way you can capture two or three items inside the parenthesis using group constructs (group matches)
- As per the question (a bit unclear and changed a lot), I find you are only interested in the items ahead of the last item. So the above regex finds items only followed by a comma and must be at least 2 such items
- The input must have a `INTERFACE(X, X, ....)` format
- Now to get the actual item set you must do the string manipulation after getting the match i.e. splitting by `,(comma)`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q59NJH/1)